# SQL_NO_CACHE per table

Tags: centos6, mysql-5.5

Over all most if not all of our tables greatly benefit from MySQL's query cache with the exception of one table. This table severely hampers the query cache to do the frequent updates. I know we can set SQL_NO_CACHE when doing a query but I wanted to know if there was a way to set it per table? Currently we are using MySQL 5.5 with plans to one day migrate to 5.6 or 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

After much research and speaking with lead MySQL devs they say there is currently no way of doing this.